# Decrypting part of AES stream

Tags: c#, io, cryptography, aes

I use AES encryption. It's ok when I encrypt and then decrypt whole file. I want to add multiple files to one encrypted. That's where the problem is. Encryption is fine, but decryption causes CryptographicException - bad data length. Is it even possible to decrypt part of file or is it encrypted as whole ? I used one cryptostream and passed there all files I want to encrypt to single file. I am trying to do opposite:

```
AesManaged aes = AES.InitAes(key, salt);
            ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
            int defChunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50;

            using (FileStream source = new FileStream(header.data.filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                foreach (CryptHeader.fileStruct file in header.data.files)
                {
                    preparePath(file.filename);

                    using (FileStream target = new FileStream(file.filename, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(target, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            long padding = source.Length - header.data.files.Sum(x => x.length);//Just test
                            int chunkSize = (defChunkSize > (int)file.length) ? (int)file.length : defChunkSize;
                            byte[] chunkData = new byte[chunkSize];
                            int bytesRead = 0;
                            int totalRead = 0;
                            while (totalRead < file.length)
                            {
                                bytesRead = source.Read(chunkData, 0, chunkSize);
                                if (bytesRead <= 0) break;
                                totalRead += bytesRead;
                                cryptoStream.Write(chunkData, 0, bytesRead);
                            }      
                            chunkData = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done the same few years ago without any problem. The logic I used is the following:

**Encryption**

1. define number of files
2. define array for keeping encrypted sizes
3. open output stream
4. seek (forced) to (number of files * 4) + 4 (assuming lengths are integers)
5. loop for encryption (encrypt- write encrypted data -assigned encrypted size)
6. seek to 0 (begin)
7. write number of files
8. write encrypted size array
9. close output stream

**Decryption**

1. open input stream
2. read number of files
3. define-read-fill array with encrypted sizes
4. loop for decryption (**read using known sizes**)
5. close output stream

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Short form:  "you can't get there from here", it's impossible.

If you look at the description of how AES works you'll see two things.

1 AES uses a block size of 128 bits, so if your files aren't multiples of 8 bytes in length the blocks in the appended part won't line up,

2: AES use uses different keys for each block according to the rijndael key schedule, this is a likely going to be a deal breaker.

If you need to be able to concatenate encrypted files either wrap them so that the joins are visible and the fragments can be individually decrypted (gzip does this when compressing)  or use a fixed substitution cypher like rot13

Answer (score 0):

It can be done and it's working. I make table during encryption containing lengths of encrypted files. Than I decrypt exact parts (with padding).